# Chrome extension to open up a specific URL in a different browser

Tags: google-chrome, url, firefox, browser, google-chrome-extension

Thank you for any help in advance!  I was wondering if there was a Chrome extension out there that would allow me to have a specific URL (when it was accessed) open up in a different browser all together (Firefox for example).  The issue I have is that I need the latest version of Chrome for certain things, but a specific build of Firefox (version 29) for others.  Primarily Chrome with the latest and greatest updates would be my default browser, but then if I could find an extension that would open up a specific URL or two in that Firefox version 29 build, that would be great!  Any thoughts?

Comment: I've heard of the LBS (Legacy Browser Support) extension for Chrome but it appears to only work with IE.  Not Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no API to do that from an extension.

Edit:

Actually, you can do that with [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). You will need to write a small Native Host module that will call browsers you want with the URL you want.

As long as you're writing it for yourself, it's an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same functionality and couldn't find anything, so I wrote a chrome extension that does exactly this.

The extension allows you to add different browsers that you already have installed on your computer, right click and choose what browser you'd like to open the current url or link in.

You can even add specific URLs to automatically load in a different browser.

Created this because at work i have to use different browsers for different websites.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/second-browser/camgemdhfmfogamncjkgddnloggffmbc

Costs 99 cents though :)

Comment: Your edits have made this answer acceptable. For reference, we require that you (A) demonstrate [how the tool/library solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself, and (B) if you are involved with it in some way, you need to [disclose your affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) within the answer itself. You've done that now, so I've undeleted this. However...the question itself is off-topic for Stack Overflow, as it's not related to programming. Somehow, it got missed, so I've also closed it now.

Comment: This new extension also works great https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copytabs/obkbjogekcjalnaebheboejhfkamadkg

Comment: The link is dead. What happened to your extension? Thank you.

Comment: @KeishaW thanks for the suggestion. It's Windows only though, and relies on a third party Windows executable.