# How to access different URL with Google Chrome extention in background, using JS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I am building my google chrome extension with functionality as follows:

1. Extention will be used only on one specific domain (like http(s)://www.abc.com/*)
2. Extention will be running(listening) all the time - on any page within the given domain
3. Upon highlighting(selecting by mouse) an ident of a course, its statistics(grade distribution) will be shown on the same page. The graph will be shown on top of the page content = doesn't matter where exactly, I will adjust that later.

Now, course statistics(graphs) are stored on the same domain, yet different page. It is needed to "go/click through" other two pages - to select the semester and desired course. Then the graph is shown.

**Question:**

- Can I(and how) access these graphs(being on another page yet being on the same domain) and display them on my current page (where I highlighted text)

**Notes:**

- I read through some other questions here like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816374/chrome-extension-and-jenkins-urls) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618545/chrome-extension-to-open-up-a-specific-url-in-a-different-browser) and came to the conclusion it should be possible since it is on the same domain however I could not find any way how to force JS to access content on another webpage.
- I have coded the part with selecting the text, capturing selected text and storing it in variable. Now I need a function (set of functions) to access different page, there in HTML find math with my selected text - click/redirect on the/with corresponding link, being redirected on another page, there copy the image and finally display this image on my page.
- Ideally, only one tab (where I select ident) will be open. But if its needed new tab with statistics can be open too..
- To access the domain described above, you have to be logged in - could be this also a problem?
- Although I program unfortunately not in JS, so all this is new to me.

Many thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: The standard `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` may work plus parsing of the response using DOMParser. Otherwise inspect the site's own requests by observing devtools network panel and see which of them get the data you need when navigating through the site.

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm, first of all, thank you very much for the answer (and sorry for the late response)! I implemented `fetch` function and it solved my question! So thanks again.

However, I have one more question. Now, I "extract" data (=data used to recreate the statistics) from a page in my _content.js_ file. I would like to pass them (anyhow) to my _popup.js_ and therefore _popup.html_.

Also data "extraction" is triggered by selecting text (in `document.addEventListener("click",...`)). How/can I send data(runtime.sendMessage) inside one of my functions in content.js.

Comment: The messaged data must be simple: string/number/boolean/null or array/object of these types.